# How to remove dynamicaly created <div> tag if img src='undefined' in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to select folder content.This folder contain images when I am selecting that folder it will select all content.plus it is taking img src undefind. 
so I need to remove that **how can I remove if src is undefined using asp.net c#**

```
<div id="cell" class="box2">
    <a href="undefined">
        <img width="260px" height="135px" src="undefined"
            alt="" 
            style="box-shadow: 1px    2px 2px #BDBDBD;
            border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;">
       </img>
    </a>
</div>
```

Code behind file:

```
protected void chbindustry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (result == false)
    {
        string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(Server.MapPath("BusinessCards"));
        string f;
        string[] ss;
        string side = chklist.SelectedValue;// RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
        foreach (ListItem li in chbindustry.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {

                ss = li.Text.Split('(');

                f = Server.MapPath("BusinessCards").ToString() + "\\" + ss[0];
                int c = f.Count();
                DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(f);
                int len = d.GetFiles().Length;
                for (int i = 1; i <= d.GetFiles().Length / 3; i++)
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("ImgPaths", "'" + "BusinessCards/" + f.Remove(0, f.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + "/" + i + ".jpg'");
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("refs", "'" + "DesignBCs.aspx?img=BusinessCards/" + f.Remove(0, f.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + "/" + i + "&Side=" + side + "'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    result = true;
}
```

Dynamically creating div:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        for (var i = 0; i < ImgPaths.length; i = i + 3) {
            var rowdiv = '<div id="row">';
            rowdiv = rowdiv + ' <div id="cell" class="box2">';
            rowdiv = rowdiv + ' <a href="' + refs[i] + '"><img width="260px" style="box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #BDBDBD; border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;" height="135px" alt="" src="' + ImgPaths[i] + '"></img></a> ';
            rowdiv = rowdiv + ' </div>';
            rowdiv = rowdiv + ' <div id="cell" class="box2">';
            rowdiv = rowdiv + '  <a href="' + refs[i + 1] + '"><img width="260px" style="box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #BDBDBD; border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;" height="135px" alt="" src="' + ImgPaths[i + 1] + '"></img></a>';
            rowdiv = rowdiv + '</div>';
            rowdiv = rowdiv + ' <div id="cell" class="box2">';
            rowdiv = rowdiv + ' <a href="' + refs[i + 2] + '"><img width="260px" style="box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #BDBDBD; border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;" height="135px" alt="" src="' + ImgPaths[i + 2] + '"></img></a>';
            rowdiv = rowdiv + '</div>';
            rowdiv = rowdiv + '</div>';
            $("#table").append(rowdiv);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using JQuery, this would work for you.
See [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/unsbr/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img[src="undefined"]').remove();
});
```

Updated [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/unsbr/1/) to remove div.

```
$('img[src="undefined"]').parent().parent().remove();
```

Comment: if i want to delete div of particular img=undefined

Comment: @user3497696 see updated demo to delete parent div. Please note this is specifically write in your current HTML markup, with a <a> tag around img then wrap with div. Edit accordingly if you change your structure.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the onError event for the image to call JavaScript function which will remove the div:

```
function imgError(divid) {
  document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'none';
    return true;
}


<img src="image.png" onerror="imgError(divid);"/>
```

you need to pass div id to function which you want to hide.

Comment: it is not possible with c#

Comment: div is creating dynamically

Comment: Definitely it is possible by the c#. But for it we need some more code to find out how you are creating dynamic html.